# How can I find small distance between polylines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, distance, line

I`m trying to find lines which have small distance between them and I am using ArcGIS 10 for this.
I had tried to make points at the both ends of the lines and to detect the distance between points and lines with "Near" but there is no result. Points are lying on the lines and I get always 0 as a result.
What is my task: to have only four lines for every square and if the lines are close one to other, they must have a complete overlap.
I had tried with topology, buffers, near (with distance, angle) and etc. and I can not find a way to detect them.
Can someone help me with this ?

And now small description for the pictures:

1 - This is the general situation. Two squares which every one has to be made from four lines.

2 - The smaller has an error. He is made from 5 lines, which is not allowed. The fifth line is starting from point 1 towards the circled area (2).

3 - Zoom in of the circled area and the problem. The lines are not overlapped. The distance between them is about several millimeters.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to merge your lines is to use the "[integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000)" tools. Be carefull when you use this tool because it modifies the input data.

If you want to detect those lines, you could use integrate on a copy of your original data, the you run "intersect" between the original and the integrated data : the result will only include the lines that were not moved by the integrate.

If you have an advanced licence, there is another workflow that you can use to measure the distance, but in fact you need to work with line segments and remove the ends, because on your example the lines are touching on one side and near returns the minimal distance:

1) feature vertices to points will give you one point at each vertex

2) create a buffer around each point with a size that reflect your tolerance (e.g. 10 cm)

3) erase the buffers from your lines

4) now you can use the near tool between lines to approximate your minimum distance

Comment: radouxju, thank you for answer !  Both solutions are working :) .  I can detect those lines now very easily .